# Why does my function not re-run with new parameter from new click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have four buttons that fill a shared target box in HTML. Each button sends a different argument ("type") to a common handler, which runs a common function, CalChoice, which fires an API with a customized URL (based on the type argument). This works correctly the first time, but any click on another button does not fire the function again with the new argument. I've run counters and alerts to prove my clicks are getting to the function, but after the first time, I can see the XHR callback in my console does not change. (I suppose I can't rule out the function is re-running with the old param, as content would not change, but I don't see the slightest burp.) In the code below, you'll find the click handler and func call at the very bottom below everything.

Why fail?

```
 function CalChoice(type) {

    if ( type == "getArt")  {
    $useURL = "my cal source here 1"
        } else if  ( type == "getNature") {
    $useURL = "my cal source here 2"
        } else if  ( type == "getFitness") {
    $useURL = "my cal source here 3"
        } else if  ( type == "getLectures") {
    $useURL = "my cal source here 4"
        }

    $('.amu-calendar').fullCalendar({

        googleCalendarApiKey: 'XXXXXX',  //our API key
        events: { googleCalendarId: $useURL
        },

        eventBackgroundColor: '#65378e',

        defaultView: 'vertWeek',

        header: {
                    left: "title",
                    center: "vertWeek month",
                    right:  "prev next"
                    },

        dayRender: function( date, cell ) { 
            // Get the current view     
            var view = $('.amu-calendar').fullCalendar('getView');

            // Check if the view is the new vertWeek - 
            // in case you want to use different views you don't want to mess with all of them
            if (view.name == 'vertWeek') {


                // Hide the widget header - looks wierd otherwise
                $('.fc-widget-header').hide();
                $('.fc-day-header').hide();

                // $('div#calendar.fc.fc-ltr.ui-widget').find('div.fc-toolbar').find('div.fc-center').html( "<a href='#switchView'>Change View</a>" );


                // Remove the default day number with an empty space. Keeps the right height according to your font.
                $('.fc-day-number').html('<div class="fc-vertweek-day">&nbsp;</div>');

                // Create a new date string to put in place  
                var this_date = date.format('ddd, MMM Do');

                // Place the new date into the cell header. 
                cell.append('<div class="fc-vertweek-header"><div class="fc-vertweek-day">'+this_date+'</div></div>');

            }
        },
        theme: true,
        themeButtonIcons: true,
        eventClick: function(gcalEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            gcalEvent.preventDefault ? gcalEvent.preventDefault() : gcalEvent.returnValue = false;  //IE8 does not recognize preventDefault so use returnvalue=false
            var eid = gcalEvent.id;
            var etitle = gcalEvent.title;
            //var eurl = gcalEvent.url;
            //var estart = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(gcalEvent.start, 'MMMM d'+', '+'h:mm tt ');
            //var eend = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(gcalEvent.end, 'h:mm tt');
            var elocation = gcalEvent.location;
            var edescription = gcalEvent.description;
            var eallday = gcalEvent.allDay;
            $('div.title-d').html(etitle);
            //$('div.datetime-d').html(estart + "-" +eend);
            $('div.location-d').html(elocation);
            $('div.description-d').html(edescription);
            $('div.framer').css({'background' : 'rgb(234,191,73)'});    // and do the same for the detail framer                    
            gcalEvent.preventDefault ? gcalEvent.preventDefault() : gcalEvent.returnValue = false;  //IE8 does not recognize preventDefault so use returnvalue=false
            return false;
        }
    });
}
//MY HANDLER

$(".accordionButton").click(function(event) {                                       //amu-calendar
    event.stopPropagation();//tried this, does not help
    var type = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log("The " + type + " button was clicked." ) //this always works but...
    CalChoice(type);// a counter in this func does increment, yet it appears it is not running with the new type...no new result.
});
```

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(type)`? Are you sure the four buttons have unique `id`s?

Comment: I don't think the problem is the function, rather your `fullCalendar` call. You need to destroy the view first. `$(..).fullCalendar('destroy');`

Comment: DavidLi -- yes, fine. If I click "art" it says "The getArt button was clicked" (getArt is the ID of the button). Nature, Fitness, Lectures, same thing.

Comment: MinusFour-- interesting. The display view is sitting there, and I am indeed trying to overwrite it. I guess I thought it would just work with new JSON. You are saying I have to manually get rid of the view first?

Comment: I'm not sure if you could reuse your other options. My guess is that you can't, so that's why I suggested to delete the calendar first.

Comment: Well, it works! I guess it is the same thing as removing a class and replacing it! Please write as answer so I can select. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't much a problem with the function call, because the argument is correct but the `fullCalendar` plugin is being stateful at some point and it will work with the previous calendar. You'll need to destroy the calendar first to create another one.

```
$('.amu-calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
```

Another way would be to remove the `eventsObject`:

```
$('.amu-calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
$('.amu-calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource' , { googleCalendarId : 'newEventURL' });
```

Comment: nah, first thing I tried. It resets that bit but the ajax won't run again, apparently because the older one still exists. When I destroy it, it is a new process with the new param.